# what is the best way to add mobile (or tablet...) detection within zf2?

Tags: zend-framework2, detection, browser-detection, mobile-devices

Is there a recommended way to perform a mobile or browser check/detection with zf2?
I am surprised there seems to be no module developed to handle this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some ways to do that:

- https://github.com/rainphp/useragent
- https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect (http://mobiledetect.net)
- https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap

Or by PHP class

- http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-browser.php

You can find a lot of snippets online, like [this](http://blog.uk-webdeveloper.co.uk/browser-detect-very-simple-oop-class-to-detect-browser/)

Comment: Mobile-Detect worked for me. There are quite a number of plugins available for various frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [neilime/ZF2 Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/neilime/zf2-mobile-detect) module and another one [nikolaposa/MobileDetectModule](https://github.com/nikolaposa/MobileDetectModule), both provides [serbanghita/Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) features.